Laptop making a helicopter noise when playing audio
I've tried everything, tried restarting the drivers, rebooting the laptop, turned off power save, none of it works. My laptop plays audio just fine, but it will randomly play this helicopter rotor kind of noise over it too? The helicopter sound also instantly stops/starts whenever I mute/unmute my audio too. It never did this on Windows. I've been dealing with this for half a year, and can't find anything to help me. It's getting on my nerves, since I play a lot of music and audio based games...
I don't know all the specs or whatever of my laptop, but I know it is a Lenovo 7 Pro Slim that uses NVidia graphics, though I'm not sure what NVidia would have to do with my audio. The first thing I did after installing Ubuntu in July was get Steam and boot up BTD6 on there, so safe to say the sound was always a thing. The Ubuntu build I'm using is the latest Desktop release, 24.10.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; so we currently don't even know what you're running which is the starting point of what we can suggest. Is it a new install? has always made this sound? or has started making the sound after a change/restart?  Some details/background & especially what Ubuntu product & release you're using is required for useful advice.

I knew I was forgetting something. I don't know all the specs or whatever of my laptop, but I know it is a Lenovo 7 Pro Slim that uses NVidia graphics, though I'm not sure what NVidia would have to do with my audio. The first thing I did after installing Ubuntu in July was get Steam and boot up BTD6 on there, so safe to say the sound was always a thing. The Ubuntu build I'm using is the latest Desktop release, 24.10.

For what it's worth, it started last week on my Lenovo thinkpad t14, running Linux Mint 22, based on Ubuntu 24.04. I didn't change any config file, so it might have appeared after a software update. It happens mostly with videos played in Firefox.
